# Is it possible to use the same GridBagLayout for multiple JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

There are two JPanels with GridBagLayout. Each JPanel uses three columns. I want the column size to be synchronized between two JPanels.

I've tried to pass the same instance of GridBagLayout and GridBagLayoutConstraints to the first and second JPanel, but the column sizes are not synchronized in this case... E.g. the first column in the first panel is bigger than the first column in the second panel.

Is it any way to make them synchronized ???

Comment: Hello! Could you include the code of your panels in the question, please? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `Is it any way to make them synchronized?` - no. Each layout manager works independently of the other layout managers. The size of each column is based on the preferred sizes of the components added to each column.